# hdc is undefined [gdi+, mfc standard application]

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi+, gdi

So my teacher gave us a chunk of code to use for double buffering.

He said "here, use this code so you don't have to sit there for hours finding out how"
Except his code does not function.

His initial usage of hdc is undefined. I tried putting it in the parameter list but that is a no go.

This is the code he gave us:

```
// Create a backbufer bmp bufer to draw to in memory.
 RECT rcClient;
 ::GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcClient);
 int left = rcClient.left;
 int top = rcClient.top;
 int width = rcClient.right - rcClient.left;
 int height = rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top;
 HDC hdcMem = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
 const int nMemDC = ::SaveDC(hdcMem);
 HBITMAP hBitmap = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);
 ::SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
 Graphics graphics(hdcMem);
 SolidBrush back(Color(255,255,255));
 graphics.FillRectangle(&back, left, top, width, height);
 // Draw to backbufer bitmap here.

 // End draw to backbufer bitmap bufer.
 // Swap bufers ie. push memory backbufer to the screen frontbufer
 RECT rcClip;
 ::GetClipBox(hdc, &rcClip);
 left = rcClip.left;
 top = rcClip.top;
 width = rcClip.right - rcClip.left;
 height = rcClip.bottom - rcClip.top;
 ::BitBlt(hdc, left, top, width, height, hdcMem, left, top, SRCCOPY);
 ::RestoreDC(hdcMem, nMemDC);
 ::DeleteObject(hBitmap);
```

Right here is where I run into the errors: `HDC hdcMem = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);`
I attempted declaring an HDC like so

```
HDC hdc = (HDC)BeginPaint((LPPAINTSTRUCT)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd->GetSafeHwnd());
```

But that doesn't compile. What do I do with this hdc?

Comment: The code clearly expects `hdc` to already be available (presumably it is the DC of the window you're trying to draw on). There should be some other textprovided explaining this.  If not then you could try the [GetDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: Don't use `BeginPaint` unless you're in the handler for the `WM_PAINT` message.

Answer (score 0):

The HDC is returned by BeginPaint, which presumably is called immediately before this code. BeginPaint takes two parameters and you are trying to call it with only one parameter. Do you have earlier exercises where you handled BeginPaint?

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to the various answers here. My knowledge of this is still fairly new, however with the help of my class mates I was able to come to a solution. Sadly I still do not know what to do with the HDC and this was the first of my problems,

```
 HDC hdcMem = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); was able to be replaced by
 HDC hdcMem = ::CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
```

and a lot of the other  code that produced warnings  such as the  hwnd was simply removed and it worked fine.